# Issue with grabbing text from SPAN using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get the start of the warranty start date from the Lenovo website using Selenium, i have successfully found the search box, where i enter the serial number and press return. I have then put a 5 second delay in and try to read the text from the span with the following.

```
    info = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='app-psp-warranty']/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/p")
    return info. Text
```

This doesn't return anything but i have confirmed the new page is loading. The following is the full XPATH and i have confirmed this works in Edge/Chrome when searching.

```
/html/body/div[2]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]

The HTML element is <span data-v-71ae5215="" class="property-value">2023-04-25</span>
```

Comment: you can use `WebDriverWait`, to wait until the required path is not found.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the way i was searching and this now works. I hadn't realised that i could count the 5th occurrence of the class.

```
    return driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "property-value")[4].text
```

Comment: Thats awesome :D

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
info = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='app-psp-warranty']/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2]")
print(info.text)
```